# Regex number range target

Tags: regex

address that ends with the value 1 to 254

**194.197.171.1-254**

My regex doesnt seem to react? What is wrong?

**^194\.197\.171\.{0,254}$**

Comment: `\.{0,254}` means maximun of 254 `\.`'s

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes so how should it be?

Comment: `^194\.197\.171\.[^0]` should suffice, unless you also need to check that the last number is correctly formatted and less than 256

Comment: @squeamishossifrage it can't be more than 256

Comment: Maybe: [`^194\.197\.171\.((1?[1-9]|10)\d?|2[0-5][0-4])$`](https://regex101.com/r/Wrco0Q/1)

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes works!

Comment: I'm glad to hear this :)